# Does git download a file if it doesn't have to?

Tags: git

Let's say I do the following four commits:

1. ADD    hello_world.txt - 1Kb
2. ADD    hello_world.jpg - 10Mb
3. REMOVE hello_world.jpg - 10Mb
4. ADD    hello_world2.txt - 1Kb

If someone checks out this repo, will they download the large "hello_world.jpg"? Or will git be smart enough to know the file isn't present if you are at the point of the most recent commit, and therefore only download the most recent needed files?

Comment: You're missing the point of git. The point is to have full history records. Your file is part of history right? So it's required to have the full record. You can always ask git to get you an incomplete repository should you want to, though it's seldom used because it is limited in functionality.

Comment: Git is version control. So hello_world.jpg is still in a previous version of your repository.

Comment: If someone doesn't need the history but only the files of the latest version, `git archive --repo=<remote_url> -o foo.tar.gz` is one of the options. Github doesn't support `git archive` but provides some restapi to do the same job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Git will download the entire `hello_world.jpg` image file, even if it is not present in the HEAD of any particular branch.  The reason for this is that if you were to checkout an earlier commit where the JPG were present, Git would need that file history to create the corresponding workspace.

For this reason, it is usually not recommended to commit large binary files, because they become a permanent fixture in your Git history.

If you have a really large file and want to avoid bringing it in locally, you could use a shallow clone.  Or, another option might be to remove the file from history using a tool like filter branch.  But the best practice is probably to not commit such a file in the first place.

Comment: I was hoping git was smart enough to only actually download hello_world.jpg if I had to revert to a previous version.

Comment: @coderama `git` is decentral. Only `clone`, `fetch`, `pull` and `push` act on remote repositories, everything else stays local and doesn't even need access to the remote repository/repositories.

Comment: @coderama said otherwise, a git repository, by design, is self sufficient. You can take it on your usb stick, take it to that remote place off the hook, work there. It also means as long as one copy of the repository exists, all others can be restored by making a copy of that one. There is no notion of "server" in git, that's a concept introduced by people's workflows because it's convenient to mark one copy as authoritative, but git doesn't enforce it or even know about such concept.

Comment: @spectras Your comment seems off topic for this question.  The OP is worried about whether a large file, once committed, will remain in the history even once it has been deleted.  The answer is in general is yes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen> It is yes indeed. I was just explaining why, expanding on Zeta's comment. That is, how the idea of being *“smart enough to only download [when needed]”* comes from misunderstanding the design goals of git. As it's designed so repositories are self-sufficient, that means each copy must have the whole information, about all files, at every point in history.

Comment: @spectras Now I got your point...so Git needs that large deleted file in its history otherwise it would have an external dependency which it aims not to have.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `git` will download the complete history. After all, it's possible to clone and check out any commit:

```
git clone url/of/repo
git checkout commit-of-large-file
```

The only part that needs network access is the initial `clone`. If you don't want the complete history, use `--depth`.

`git filter-branch` can help you if you want to remove the large file completely from your history, but that can lead to several problems and must be used with care.